# QGIS Server struggling to load projects

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-server

I'm trying to setup QGIS server as a local host for now so that I can test it out and see if it's what after. I'm completely new to server setup, but I've managed to get the server to respond to a Get Capabilities request such as:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

But when I try to launch a Get Capabilities request for a QGIS project stored on the server such as this one:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/?MAP=/cgi-bin/home/qgis/projects/world/world.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe

Then I get an "Access Forbidden 403" response and the server produces the error log that I've attached below.

Where am I going wrong here?

[image]